# Custom audio player of facebook like soundcloud.com

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

When I share soundcloud.com audio mp3 in facebook it display audio player of soundcloud in facebook. we can play mp3 directly from facebook, suppose youtube: when we share youtube video link, it directly play video in facebook

I want to know how can i configure audio player like this?

I have tried to find lots of facebook graph documentation but nothing is useful for my issue.

please help me regarding this.

Comment: Your keyword is Feed Gaming. Also this is mainly for Games, it is basically just about embedding a flash player object within an Open Graph object. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/

Comment: is there any way to develop audio player like youtube video show on facebook?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do this. It's a different story with video, but I have never seen a playable audio in FB.

Comment: so you have to check soundcloud.com.